# Using different time for same azure time trigger function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

Can I trigger the same azure function for 2 different times say one for 9:30 AM and another for 5:00 PM everyday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is impossible.

You should divided into two parts, your requirements cannot be written in only one cron expression.

You should use two timetrigger with below expression:

`0 30 9 * * *`

`0 0 17 * * *`

Dividing into two functions is not very complicated. If you are based on a consumption plan, charges are based on the number of runs, this means it doesn’t cost more in terms of cost. In short, a single cron expression cannot achieve your needs.

---

By the way, if you want 9:00 AM and 5:00 PM, you can use:

`0 0 9,17 * * *`

Comment: Thanks, I even thought that it is impossible to do it in the same function as the times that I have selected were not able to fit in CRON expression.